# Dual normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let random variable X has dual normal distribution with mean vector $\mu$ and
>
> covariance matrix $\sum$
>
> $$X= \left ( \begin{array}{ccc} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{array} \right )$$
> $$\mu= \left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 3\\ 5\end{array} \right )$$
> $$\sum= \left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 4 & -2\\ -2 &4 \end{array} \right )$$
> Let $y = 2x_1 - 3x_2$ Find $P(y>4)$

I know how to find $P((x_1, x_2) \subset D )$, but i have no idea how to find $P(y>4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

condition on one of the variables:
$$
\mathbb{P}[y>4] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{P}[y > 4|x_1=t] f_{x_1}(t) dt...
$$